# Quit unexpectedly again and again while trying to build an .ipa file

Tags: xcode, xcode5.1

I am trying to distribute my universal application via Ad-Hoc distribution.

Being a first timer, i have been watching a lot of videos and going through apple documentation on how to do it.

I have applied the following steps:

- Registering with apple developer's program (as admin not team agent).
- Register the test devices.
- creating/downloading a provisioning certificate.
- creating an ad-hoc provision profile.
- creating an xarchive file via xcode
- now in the organiser I try to create an ipa file after selecting the correct certificate and provisioning profile in the process, it asks me to save the ipa file.

But when it reaches this step, Xcode quits (crashes) every time.

Have checked and rechecked that if i am selecting the correct options in the process or not and still not able to generate the ipa file.

I have tries building it for 12-15 times but every time Xcode crash happens.

> Xcode : 5.1.1
>
> application : universal
>
> iOs target : 7 or later
>
> loading data from web services : YES
>
> Storyboards : YES

Any Suggestion would be a great help.

Comment: Sounds like you are you trying to submit the binary for review, is this the case? Theres another way (an easier one) that does not require building the bloody ipa.

Comment: ok, so how can i distribute my application to the test devices remotely other than the above mentioned method?

Comment: The file you submit to apple for review of your application. Thats called the binary.

Comment: I am not trying to submit via app store i just want to send it to my test devices remotely

Answer (score 0):

### Possible solution

1. Quit XCode
2. Go to derived data's folder, delete them (also from trash).
3. Open XCode clean project and try to build it again

Comment: Any luck by doing this?

Comment: No Luck, still stuck at same place

Comment: Have you tried to update XCode, and check also if is your version is beta because Apple does not let you to publish with beta version!